# My code works but it should not and I dont understand why

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat-deploy

So I have code where I am minting an NFT. I have my metadata inside of a function called tokenURI(). But when I go to run my script to deploy, I never actually called on this function but it somehow still mints my NFT with the correct metadata. I am happy that it is working, but, realistically it should not work at all. Why does my tokenURI() function get invoked?

Github repo in case needed: https://github.com/jaysnel/js-nft

Command being ran:

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`

My .sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

// OpenZeppelin Contracts and hardhat
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract JSNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721 ('jsNFT', 'JSNFT'){
        console.log('NFT contract deployed');
    }

    
    function makeJSNFT() public {
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _tokenIds.increment();
    }


    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(_tokenId));
        console.log("An NFT SVG w/ ID %s has been minted to %s", _tokenId, msg.sender);
        return string(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "data:application/json;base64",
                "data:application/json;base64,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"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

deploy.js:

```
const deployContract = async () => {
    const nftContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('JSNFT');
    const nftContract = await nftContractFactory.deploy();
    await nftContract.deployed();
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", nftContract.address);

    // Call the function
    let txn = await nftContract.makeJSNFT()
    await txn.wait()
  };


const main = async () => {
    try {
      await deployContract();
      process.exit(0);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };
  
  main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deploy script mints an NFT using the `makeJSNFT` function. `tokenURI`has nothing to do with minting in itself, it only lets you fetch the metadata of already existing ones

Comment: This makes sense somewhat. So after trying some things out, you are correct in that it fetcches the metadata of an already existing item. But, it doesnt explain how the correct NFT is getting minted. The metadata is living inside of `tokenURI` so I just updated it to a brand new image that has not been minted before. This new image was minted successfully. So how does `makeJSNFT` know that this new image should have been minted since that data lives outside of the function?

Comment: `makeJSNFT` and `tokenURI` doesnt create any image "by themselves". `makeJSFNT` creates a token, and `tokenURI`'s code basically just says "if the token doesn't exist, revert, if it exists, return [that long string of characters that starts with "data:application/json;base64..."]". That string is a Base4 encoded JSON, that resolves to https://gyazo.com/bb5ce389ae86f3d3484bf20bb576b7d7, which contains another base64 string, which resolves to https://gyazo.com/ce91f169b22aa2b6d229a0279a8a96f1

Comment: Okay so each time I update to a new image in the base64 string and then i deploy this, I can see this new image on Openseas testnet. So is it safe to say that it is Opensea that is calling the `tokenURI` function and that function looks at the token ID of that specific item on Opensea and returns this metadata since that is the metadata that is living on that specific contract?

Comment: That's exactly how it works, yes :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand this better!!